# how to generate a database table from an entity type?

Tags: entity-framework

How to create an entity type and then generate a database table from it? 
I know this feature was not supported two years ago in EF, what about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, Entity Framework introduced these feature.
Basically, with only two steps is sufficient for this, please see below steps to go:

1. Create your Entity

   ```
   public class Resturant
   {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create Context class

   ```
   public class OdeToFoodDb: DbContext
   {
      public DbSet<Resturant> Resturants { get; set; }
   }
   ```

However, you may need more coding in Global.ascx for advance options but these are the basic steps.

A database named "OdeToFoodDb" will create and a table named "Resturant" also will create by these steps.

Answer (score 2):

You've got 2 options:

[Entity Framework Model First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362) where you create the model first and then generate the database from that or
[Entity Framework Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) where you create normal Poco objects and generate the database from that.

I've personally used Entity Framework Code First for MVC development and it works like a charm, it really is an awesome feature and easy to use.